# What material can withstand continuous working temperature of 1000 degree Celsius?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering

I'm designing a block for creating turbulence inside a traditional furnace. I would like to know about a material which is economical and can be put into operation for more than 2 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most industrial furnaces are lined with [fire bricks](https://theconstructor.org/building/fire-bricks-properties-types-uses/29377/) to ensure long operating times at high temperatures. Depending on the properties of the bricks, particularly the grade of the [fire clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_clay), temperatures up to 1640 $\small\sf{^o}$C can be tolerated.

> Fire clay contains two major constituents- silica and alumina, of which, the silica percentage varies from 60 to 70% and alumina varies from 25 to 35%

Comment: If the op wants to create turbulence will fire clay stand the friction?

Comment: @SolarMike presumably we are talking about turbulence in gas not liquid, at those temperatures.